# Resource id as key name in JSON response

Tags: json, rest

Is it recommended that I use a resource id (eg. student id/class id) as a key name in a JSON response of a REST API.

eg.

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": "success",
  "data": {
    "class_details": {
      "123": {
        "student_name": "Abc",
        "performance": [
          {
            "date": "2015-03-26 14:56:19",
            "marks": "98",
            "quiz_id":1
          },
          {
            "date": "2015-03-21 14:56:19",
            "marks": "92",
            "quiz_id":2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here 123 is the student id.

Comment: Consider maintenance issues 1 year down the line... a dev would think well erm wtf is 123 for.

Comment: I guess the real question here is why don't you want to give the student id key a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harshit i hope this will answer your question

Is it recommended that I use a resource id (eg. student id/class id) as a key name in a JSON response of a REST API.

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": "success",
  "data": {
    "**1546**": {
      "**123**": {
        "student_name": "Abc",
        "**12456**": [
          {
            "date": "2015-03-26 14:56:19",
            "marks": "98",
            "quiz_id":1
          },
          {
            "date": "2015-03-21 14:56:19",
            "marks": "92",
            "quiz_id":2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you can judge what does the 1546, 123, represents, they you can go with this.

But incase you cannot judge this, this is a bad approach. Any one else other then you or even you, if cannot judge a key in a json then this is practically a bad practice.